# How do I use COM classes in PHP with ubuntu OS?

Tags: php

I can't use COM classes in PHP. It displays errors. How do I enable and use COM classes in Ubuntu 9.04?

Comment: What errors does it display? "It doesn't work" won't get you answers to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/com.requirements.php

> COM functions are only available for the Windows version of PHP.

COM is a Windows technology. What are you even trying to use it for on Linux?

Comment: then how can I read the document and store database in linux?

Comment: @Pandi Read *what* document? You'll need to be a lot more specific if you need answers.